# adding an id attribute to q-input

Tags: quasar-framework

Say I have the following q-input:

```
<q-input
    v-model="form.email"
    inverted-light
    color="white"
    stack-label="Email:"
    type="email"
    @blur="$v.form.email.$touch"
    :error="$v.form.email.$error"/>
```

I'd like to be able to make it so that if the domain of the email is `mydomain.com` that the form action will change to another website (without csrf protection) and the POST will be made to that website instead of the main one.

To do this I was thinking I could use jQuery. eg. `$('#email').val().replace(/^.+@/, '') == 'mydomain.com'` then change the form action and submit.

The only problem is: I don't know how to set an `id` attribute on `q-input`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of early Quasar 1.4.2 (November of this year) you can specify the id value on the resulting html generated by q-input by using the "for" property (see the end of the behavior properties: https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#QInput-API).

So, for example, you could add `for="myInputId"`:

```
<q-input
    v-model="form.email"
    inverted-light
    color="white"
    stack-label="Email:"
    type="email"
    @blur="$v.form.email.$touch"
    :error="$v.form.email.$error"
    for="myInputId"
/>
```

The id attribute with value "myInputField" will end up on the resulting `<input>` element in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Not using the "for" in the elements gave me a lot of headaches because the Jest snapshot generated random IDs